# Unity 2D - zoom in =ok, zoom out = borked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I hope someone can help. Im trying to create a little script that zooms in to my player and back out - toggling.
The zoom in works fine, but when I try to zoom back out it doesn't work, it gets stuck. I've created a bool to ensure it only runs the code when it needs to and I'm wondering if that is what's causing the error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraZoom : MonoBehaviour
{

public float zoom = 10f;
public float normal = 3.471398f;
public float smooth = 5f;
private bool isZoomed = false;

public Camera cam;
public GameObject player;

// lock the camera settings
public float LockedX = 0f;
public float LockedY = 0f;
public float LockedZ = 0f;
private bool hasBeenZoomed =  false;

Vector3 targetPos;

private Transform playerTransform;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    targetPos = transform.position;
    playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("z")) { isZoomed = !isZoomed; }
    if (isZoomed == true)
    {
        ZoomInToPlayer();
        hasBeenZoomed = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (hasBeenZoomed)
        {
            ZoomOutFromPlayer();
            hasBeenZoomed = false;
        }
    }
}

void ZoomInToPlayer()
{
    // By default the target x and y coordinates of the camera are it's current x and y coordinates.
    float targetX = transform.position.x;
    float targetY = transform.position.y;

    // ... the target x coordinate should be a Lerp between the camera's current x position and the player's current x position.
    targetX = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, playerTransform.position.x, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    //Debug.Log("player x is " + playerTransform.position.x + " and TargetX is " + targetX);

    // ... the target y coordinate should be a Lerp between the camera's current y position and the player's current y position.
    targetY = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.y, playerTransform.position.y, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    //Debug.Log("player y is " + playerTransform.position.y+ " and TargetY is " + targetY);


    // Set the camera's position to the target position with the same z component.
    cam.transform.position = new Vector3(targetX, targetY, transform.position.z);

    // Change the size of the camera viewport
    cam.orthographicSize = Mathf.Lerp(cam.orthographicSize, zoom, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
}

void ZoomOutFromPlayer()
{
    // By default the target x and y coordinates of the camera are it's current x and y coordinates.
    float targetX;
    float targetY;

    // Change the size of the camera viewport
    cam.orthographicSize = Mathf.Lerp(cam.orthographicSize, normal, Time.deltaTime * smooth);

    // ... the target x coordinate should be a Lerp between the camera's current x position and the original x position.
    targetX = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, LockedX, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    // ... the target y coordinate should be a Lerp between the camera's current y position and the original y position.
    targetY = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.y, LockedY, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    // Set the camera's position to the target position with the same z component.
    cam.transform.position = new Vector3(targetX, targetY, transform.position.z);

}
}
```

Comment: Every time you write `if (something == true)`, it's better to substitute it with `if (something)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraZoom : MonoBehaviour
{

public float zoom = 10f;
public float normal = 3.471398f;
public float smooth = 5f;
private bool isZoomed = false;
private bool isZoomFinished = true; // the animation zoom is over ?

public Camera cam;
public GameObject player;

public float LockedX = 0f;
public float LockedY = 0f;
public float LockedZ = 0f;
private bool hasBeenZoomed =  false;

Vector3 targetPos;

private Transform playerTransform;

void Start()
{
    targetPos = transform.position;
    playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("z") && isZoomFinished) { 
        isZoomed = !isZoomed; 
        isZoomFinished = false;
    }

    if (isZoomed && !isZoomFinished)
    {
        ZoomInToPlayer();

    }
    else if (!isZoomed && !isZoomFinished)
    {
       ZoomOutFromPlayer()
    }
}

float delta = 0;

void ZoomInToPlayer()
{
    delta += smooth * Time.deltaTime;


    //Cam size
    cam.orthographicSize = Mathf.Lerp(cam.orthographicSize, zoom, delta);

    //Cam pos
    float targetX = transform.position.x;
    float targetY = transform.position.y;
    targetX = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, playerTransform.position.x, delta);
    targetY = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.y, playerTransform.position.y, delta);
    cam.transform.position = new Vector3(targetX, targetY, transform.position.z);



    // is animation over ?
    if(delta >= 1) {
        isZoomFinished = true;
        delta = 0;
    }
}

void ZoomOutFromPlayer()
{

    delta += smooth * Time.deltaTime;

    //Cam size
    cam.orthographicSize = Mathf.Lerp(cam.orthographicSize, normal, delta);

    //Cam pos
    float targetX;
    float targetY;
    targetX = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, LockedX, delta);
    targetY = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.y, LockedY, delta);
    cam.transform.position = new Vector3(targetX, targetY, transform.position.z);

    // is animation over ?
    if(delta >= 1) {
        isZoomFinished = true;
        delta = 0;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks.   So why does it not zoom back out to the correct location, 0,0 as indicated in the LockedX/Y variables.   Is there a way to zoom AND move at the same time, ie the transform and the changing the imagesize?

Comment: SILLY ME, its the delta variable, once ALL get the same delta variable then they work on the same timeline.  Working now thanks. Now all I need to do is work out how to slow the animation down and yet still allow the z key to be recognised.  Smooth set to 1.1 seems best so far but there seems to be a long wait once it has zoomed in before the z key is recognised.

Answer (score 3):

Your methods `ZoomInToPlayer` and `ZoomOutFromPlayer` are written in a way that suggests that they should be called once per frame for the duration of the zoom in/out animation. However, `ZoomOutFromPlayer` will only be called once, because `Update`, when `ZoomOutFromPlayer` is called, the `hasBeenZoomed` is immediately set to false.

What you're trying to do here, essentially, is a simple [Finite State Machine](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html). I suggest researching this design pattern a little more — it will help you noticing the sources of such problems and structuring your code in a better way.

In this particular case, a good way to prevent this problem when designing your code would be to write something akin to "API documentation" for yourself, when writing your methods. For `ZoomOutFromPlayer`, it would read something like this:

> Call every frame when you want to perform zoom-out animation, until the animation is complete.

After you written (and read) such a description, you should immediately notice a red flag — "until the animation is complete"? So, the code that calls this method should somehow take track of whether the animation is complete or not, during a separate mechanism? Wouldn't it make it really easy to use this method incorrectly? Well, that's exactly what happened here.

Instead, what you could've done, is to create two different methods, `ZoomInUpdate` and `ZoomOutUpdate`, with descriptions that would read something like this:

> Call every frame when the camera should be zoomed out/zoomed in.

This way, using this methods is a lot easier, and you can safely throw out additional logic with `hasBeenZoomed` out. Just call these methods every frame, and ensure (inside these methods) that they change the camera settings with a certain speed, if these settings need to be changed, or otherwise do nothing.